# Register font from byte array in iText

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

Is it possible to register a font from a byte array, instead of using file paths?

The FontFactory class has two methods for registering fonts. Both use file/folder paths to register fonts:

- [Register](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/FontFactory.html#register(java.lang.String))
- [RegisterDirectory](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/FontFactory.html#registerDirectory(java.lang.String))

I looked into the iText source for clues, but I don't understand how the font files end up in the PDF document eventually.

Does anyone know how to register and embed a font (.ttf) from a byte array?
I am using iTextSharp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `Font` from a `byte[]`, but in that case, you can't use the `FontFactory`. Instead you need to create a `BaseFont` instance using the `createFont` method, see http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html for the different options.

Once you have a `BaseFont` instance, you can easily create a `Font` object:

Suppose that `fBytes` is a `byte[]`, then you'd have:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
    "myFont", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
    true, fBytes, null);
Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
```

The method accepts two `byte[]` parameters because Type 1 fonts consist of two files: a metrics file (AFM or PFM) and a font binary (PFB). For all other fonts (TTF, OTF,...), the second `byte[]` parameter should be `null`.

There is currently no way to add such a font to the `FontFactory` as a "registered font".

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice if the FontFactory could "register" them, but at least I have a solution now :)

Answer (score 4):

When giving your font a name you need to add .ttf to the end or you will get the following error:

Font 'myFont' with 'Identity-H' is not recognized.

Adding .ttf fixed this error for me.

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
    "myFont.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
    true, fBytes, null);
Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
```